# Why do g++ binaries have a significantly slower startup time than clang++?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, binaryfiles, clang++

Whenever I compile code using `g++`, I've noticed that when I run the binary repeatedly, it runs significantly slower than when I compile with `clang++`.

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << '\n';
}
```

script.sh

```
for ((i=0; i<2000; ++i)); do
    ./a.out
done
```

---

Compiling using g++:
`g++-11 -O2 test.cpp`
`time bash script.sh` -> `10.32s user 5.37s system 88% cpu 17.751 total`

Compiling using clang++:
`clang++ -O2 test.cpp`
`time bash script.sh` -> `1.42s user 1.50s system 69% cpu 4.223 total`

---

This is extremely annoying as I need to use `g++`, but I also need to speed up the binary to make it easier to stress test my code, so an explanation or fix would be welcome.

**Note**: GCC (11.3, via homebrew), clang (13.1, apple/homebrew (both seem to be the same))

Comment: try compiling with optimizations turned on.  measuring unoptimized code is kind of comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Benchmarking without enabling optimizations is completely pointless. The compilers will not make any attempt to produce a performant executable. Add `-O2` to both compiler invocations to enable a good default amount of optimizations.

Comment: @user17732522 Adding -O2 seems to make g++ perform even worse.

Comment: @mqc999 Well, then there is a point to your question, but without some optimization flag it is not reasonable to expect the results to be similar. Also, given that you simply output one line, most of the time spent is probably going to be spent in the program startup and the C and C++ runtime initialization. I am not sure whether you really need to optimize for that part of the program execution.

Comment: @mqc999 -- This is a poor indication that g++ has slower binaries than clang++.  It's like comparing sorting 10 items using bubble sort and quicksort to see which is faster.  Of course bubble sort will probably beat quick sort.  But when the number of items is increased to 1000, 10000, etc. you see the difference.  Having a one line `cout` program is not realistic.  Profile a full program that actually performs meaningful tasks (sorting, searching, etc.) and then see which program is faster.

Comment: I'm not surprised that Apple's Clang generates faster binaries than third-party compilers, since you're in his territory. The same as ICC compiler for Intel's CPU. Have you tried the upstream Clang, e.g. the one installed with Homebrew?

Comment: Long shot: you have an M1 or M2 Mac, your gcc does not have support for that yet but builds an x86_64 executable, and you're essentially measuring how long it takes Rosetta to launch a process.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I misphrased my question; I'm not asking if g++ is faster/slower than clang++, because I'm pretty certain that they will both run in a similar amount of time on any large input. However, I'm more intersted on why g++ has some some considerable startup time whenever I execute the binary.

Comment: @VainMan Homebrew clang seems to be the same as apple clang, and this problem doesn't apply to gcc, only g++.

Comment: @mqc999 Confusingly enough, "gcc" can refer to both the Gnu Compiler Collection (including g++) and to just its C compiler.

Comment: @molbdnilo Homebrew's gcc does build arm executables today.

Answer (score 1):

> this problem doesn't apply to gcc, only g++

It turns out that this is because g++ links the executable to libstdc++ by default.

The example can be reduced to

```cpp
// test.cpp
int main() {}
```

With linking and loading libstdc++:

```
❯ g++ test.cpp && otool -L a.out
a.out:
    /opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.29.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
❯ ls -lh /opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libstdc++.6.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 vainman  wheel   2.3M Jul  4 01:59 /opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libstdc++.6.dylib
❯ time bash script.sh
bash script.sh  6.27s user 3.58s system 94% cpu 10.468 total
```

Without linking and loading libstdc++:

```
❯ g++ -nodefaultlibs test.cpp -lSystem && otool -L a.out
a.out:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
❯ time bash script.sh
bash script.sh  0.35s user 0.96s system 72% cpu 1.804 total
```

clang++ also tries linking to `/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib` but the file doesn't seem exists.

```
❯ clang++ test.cpp && otool -L a.out
a.out:
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1300.23.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
❯ ls /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
ls: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib: No such file or directory
```

Update: Found [macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-big-sur-11_0_1-release-notes#:%7E:text=New%20in%20macOS,in%20the%20cache.):

> New in macOS Big Sur 11.0.1, the system ships with a built-in dynamic linker cache of all system-provided libraries. As part of this change, copies of dynamic libraries are no longer present on the filesystem. Code that attempts to check for dynamic library presence by looking for a file at a path or enumerating a directory will fail. Instead, check for library presence by attempting to dlopen() the path, which will correctly check for the library in the cache. (62986286)